# Can't access UI from a delegate?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I got this code:

```
GrooveOnDownload *dlg = [[GrooveOnDownload alloc] init];

NSURLDownload *dw = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:dlg];
```

It starts the download in a delegate class with outlets for UI controls. But for some reason controls don't respond to direct messages from the delegate.

```
//Header of the delegate
@interface GrooveOnDownload : NSObject {
IBOutlet id downloadButton;
//...

//Implementation 
//...
[downloadButton setEnabled:FALSE]; // Doesn't work
//...
```

**Any ideas?**

*It is my fourth day of Mac development so I don't know much about the platform.*

**Edit :** 2010-05-28 01:03:41.486 GrooveOnLite[3303:a0f] Download button = (null)

**Edit 2 :**

[image]

**Edit 3 :**
I miss Windows .....

**Edit 4**
In Win32 you send one window message to the button. Everything is handled by WndProc loop. It is damn simple. In Mac you have this magical interface builder which somehow gets all that crap working. The delegate gets called by some withcraft magic. The rest of the classes are connected by some 'magical' force. In windows there is an **tmain** function which is the entry point. That's it! No retarded outlets and such shit.

Comment: The request does work and it does download the file but I can't access the progress bar and the button from the delegate.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line that calls `setEnabled:`.  Ensure that `downloadButton` is actually an instance of a button object like you expect it to be.

Comment: Your screenshot makes it look like things are set up correctly. Are you sure it's the same GrooveOnDownload object in both cases? Your code sample makes it look like you're creating a new instance, which won't have those connections.

Comment: It could be that. How do I reuse that class from IB ?

Comment: Presumably some other object (maybe your AppDelegate) will have an outlet to that GrooveOnDownload instance. Instead of creating new GrooveOnDownloads, just use the one attached to that outlet.

Comment: Also, you should know that the objects in Interface Builder aren't classes, they're actual instances of those classes. Think of them as "freeze-dried" instances (under the hood, they're just serialized objects, if that helps make it more clear).

Comment: How do I access it when it is in the delegate? I don't think it is defined ...

Comment: Create an outlet in your app delegate, the same way you created and connected the outlet in your GrooveOnDownload. When your app launches, the AppKit runtime will recreate the objects and their connections and you can access them like any other property. So, in your app delegate, you'll have a line like `IBOutlet GrooveOnDownload *grooveOnDownload;` and you'll use IB to connect that outlet to the actual object.

Comment: And how do I access it in the delegate?

Comment: Just start using the `grooveOnDowload` property. You could, for instance, say `NSURLDownload *dw = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:grooveOnDownload];`

Comment: grooveOnDownload is undefined ....

Comment: Never thought coding for Mac would be more difficult than coding for Win32

Comment: It's not so bad, you just haven't fully grokked Interface Builder. I had the same experience: once you get IB, Mac development will make a lot more sense. It's just serialized objects. Once that 'clicks,' you'll get it.

Comment: So can I get that to work?
Thats what IB produced:
@interface GrooveOnLiteAppDelegate : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
    IBOutlet id dwOutlet;
}
- (IBAction)jj:(id)sender;
@end

Comment: dwOutlet is undefined in GrooveOnSearch though

Comment: Would you mind helping me via IM? The deadline for this is 12 o'clock today. That is in 10 hours and I need some sleep ... :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how else to explain this. It sounds like you really need to review how Interface Builder works. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No , I am porting an application

Comment: I see. Well, my point still stands: a more careful reading of the Interface Builder guide sounds like what you need. IB is the most unusual part of Mac development, so don't get discouraged if it doesn't make sense at first.

Comment: Writing a massive JSON API was quite simple even though it took two days. And now I am spending an indefinate amount of time on disabling a button ...

Comment: Okay, now you're getting mad. Get some sleep. Remember that it's just software :) Cocoa isn't worse than Win32, you just aren't used to it. None of it is magic, you just need time to let the concepts sink in.

Comment: Awww ... please help me , I need to finish this. This is probably the last time I'm coding something for this platform.

Comment: Sorry, bud. I've reached the limit of how much help I'm willing to give to someone who sounds like they don't want to learn. If you really need this done, email me (justin AT bleedingwolf DOT com) and we'll talk about consulting fees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it sounds obvious, but is everything connected correctly in Interface Builder?

**Edit**

If the download is on a separate thread, then fbrereto is correct and you'll need to perform the selector on the main thread. Your code would need to be changed to look like this:

```
[downloadButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setEnabled:)
    withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
    waitUntilDone:YES];
```

A few notes: in Objective-C the keyword `NO` is used instead of `FALSE`. It's a primitive type, so in order to use it here we had to box it in a `NSNumber` object. The `waitUntilDone` argument does exactly what you would expect, and you can change that to `NO` if you'd rather not wait.

**Edit 2**

Here's a more complete code example about how to accomplish what I think you want, which is to reuse a single instance of GrooveOnDownload from your app delegate. I'm assuming that your app delegate class is called GrooveOnLiteAppDelegate.

```
// GrooveOnLiteAppDelegate.h
@interface GrooveOnLiteAppDelegate : NSObject
{
    IBOutlet GrooveOnDownload *grooveOnDownload;
    // other properties go here
}

// your method signatures go here
@end

// GrooveOnLiteAppDelegate.m
@implementation GrooveOnLiteAppDelegate

- (void)mySuperAwesomeMethod
{
    // it's up to you to figure out what method to put this in and
    // how to call it
    NSURLDownload *dw = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:grooveOnDownload];
}

@end
```

Given that code in your app delegate, you'll have an outlet in IB that you can connect to your GrooveOnDownload object in IB. If you do that, then `grooveOnDownload` will be a pointer to that object.

Comment: Two outlets are set up in the interface builder. One for the progress bar and one for the button. I'm pretty sure everything is correct.

Comment: Add a line like `NSLog(@"Download button = %@", downloadButton);` If it comes out as `(null)`, then downloadButton isn't set correctly.

Comment: 2010-05-28 01:03:41.486 GrooveOnLite[3303:a0f] Download button = (null)

Comment: Yep, there you go. downloadButton isn't connected to anything, so any messages you send to it will be ignored. You probably haven't connected the actual button in Interface Builder to your outlet.

Comment: I have - downloadButton -> Round Rect Button

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Here's what you need to do: in Interface Builder, select your GrooveOnDownload object and in the inspector, choose the 'Connections' tab. Drag from the circle next to 'downloadButton' onto the actual button in your view. That should make the connection.

Comment: I deleted the old outlet and remade it just to be sure. It made no difference

Comment: My code is located in a different class which doesn't interact with the delegate. The delegate is empty. If that method is in delegate it is virtually useless.

Comment: Creating an outlet in GrooveOnSearch (Which is the class which has all the code in it) didn't help ...

Comment: Or how do I even call 'superAwesomeMethod' ?

Answer (score 3):

All UI calls have to be made on the main thread; if the download is happening in the background your delegate may be getting notified on a thread other than the main one, in which case a call to a UI element would have to be done through something like [`-[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:) or another related API.

Comment: Can I have an example of accessing my button that way?

Comment: [downloadButton
  performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setEnabled:)
  withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
  waitUntilDone:NO]